# Symbolic evaluation of expressions containing relational operators, possibly using Maxima

Tags: maxima

I'm looking for either another tool that will do symbolic evaluation of relational expressions, or perhaps a Maxima package that extends Maxima to enable such a feature.

As is, Maxima does not do this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know maxima can work with relational operators in the manual:

http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_7.html#SEC39

```
(%i1) [x, y, z] : [123, 456, 789];
(%o1)                    [123, 456, 789]
(%i2) is (x < y);
(%o2)                         true
(%i3) maybe (y > z);
(%o3)                         false
(%i4) if x >= z then 1 else 0;
(%o4)                           0
(%i5) block ([S], S : 0, for i:1 while i <= 100 do S : S + i, 
             return (S));
(%o5)                         5050
```

or even solve inequalities:

```
﻿(%i4) load(fourier_elim)$
(%i5) fourier_elim([(x+1)*(x+2)>0],[x]);
(%o5)                       [- 1 < x] or [x < - 2]
```